# Trouble install Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, raspberrypi

So I'm trying to install the LTS server version on my Pi 3 B+

I flash the image using the Raspberry Pi Imager tool and that seems fine. This is the 64 bit version.

I insert the SD card into the Pi and have a keyboard, mouse, and HDMI monitor attached. No ethernet though I could add that. I'd prefer WiFi for the moment.

When I power on the Pi it won't boot correctly. It displays this:

[image]

I'm not sure if I need to set some configuration files on the SD card before attempting to boot or what? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using an older Dell keyboard with a built-in hub for the mouse, would you? If so, disconnect the keyboard/mouse until *after* the boot cycle completes 

Comment: Hmm I'll give that a go. It's not a Dell keyboard. I'm using a Corsair mechanical keyboard and a Steel Series Sensei mouse. I'll try booting without those connected.

Comment: Hah that worked! I was able to plug them back in after booting and everything worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out what was wrong.

Disconnecting my keyboard and mouse allowed it to boot. I plugged them back in and everything was fine from that point on.